# Nexus player does not wake up with TV

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, android-tv

My nexus player does not wake up when I turn on my tv. On the tv it says it does not have signal.

If I unplug and plug the HDMI cable it works! This is a very annoying issue.

Do you know how to fix it?

What might be the problem? My TV, my HDMI cable or the nexus player?

Comment: What kind of TV is it? Are you plugged in directly to the TV, or through a receiver?

Comment: I have a philips 32' (32PFL6615D) and the HDMI cable is connect directly to the TV. I have already tried all the HDMI ports of the TV, all have the same problem.